# Problem with importing .tiff image

Tags: import, image

I am trying to import and display this image in Mathematica (v10.0.2)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35018860/test.tiff

however I did not succeed. Any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is from your image (unable to open in any image editor), not the `Import`

Comment: @Valacar You are right. It can not be opened with a 'normal'  image editor/viewer but you can open it with http://www.saxsgui.com/ . Maybe the problem is finding out the right file encoding format? Can this be done in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

I can open this image with mma 11.0.1.

```
image = Import [
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35018860/test.tiff"];

Options[image, MetaInformation]
```

The image info is:

```
{MetaInformation -> <|"Exif" -> <|"NewSubfileType" -> "Primary image",
      "ImageWidth" -> 487, "ImageLength" -> 619, 
     "BitsPerSample" -> 32, "Compression" -> "Uncompressed", 
     "PhotometricInterpretation" -> "Black Is Zero", 
     "ImageDescription" -> "# Pixel_size 172e-6 m x 172e-6 m

      # Silicon sensor, thickness 0.000320 m

      # Exposure_time 4800.000000 s

      # Exposure_period 4832.000000 s

      # Tau = 383.8e-09 s

      # Count_cutoff 1077896 counts

      # Threshold_setting: 4024 eV

      # Gain_setting: high gain (vrf = -0.150)

      # N_excluded_pixels = 14

      # Excluded_pixels: badpix_mask.tif

      # Flat_field: (nil)

      # Trim_file: p300k0149_E8048_T4024_vrf_m0p15.bin

      # Image_path: /data/datatemp/

      # Ratecorr_lut_directory: (nil)

      # Retrigger_mode: 0", 
     "Model" -> "PILATUS 300K-20Hz, S/N 3-0149-20Hz", 
     "StripOffsets" -> 5988, "RowsPerStrip" -> 619, 
     "StripByteCounts" -> 1205812, "XResolution" -> 88, 
     "YResolution" -> 88, "Software" -> "TVX TIFF v 1.3", 
     "DateTime" -> 
      DateObject[{2016, 12, 7}, 
       TimeObject[{18, 2, 22.}, TimeZone -> 1.], TimeZone -> 1.], 
     "Artist" -> 
      "<?xml version= 1.0  ?><SAXSLABparameters><param name= \
det_pixel_size >172e-6 172e-6</param><param name= det_thickness \
>0.000320</param><param name= det_exposure_time \
>4800.000000</param><param name= det_exposure_period \
>4832.000000</param><param name= det_tau >383.8e-09</param><param \
name= det_count_cutoff >1077896</param><param name= \
det_threshold_setting >4024</param><param name= det_n_excluded_pixels \
>14</param><param name= det_excluded_pixels \
>badpix_mask.tif</param><param name= det_flat_field \
>(nil)</param><param name= det_trim_directory \
>p300k0149_E8048_T4024_vrf_m0p15.bin</param><param name= datatype \
>tiff</param><param name= detectortype >PILATUS 300K</param><param \
name= detector_sn >dec427</param><param name= meastype \
></param><param name= start_timestamp >Wed Dec 07 18:15:24 \
2016</param><param name= end_timestamp ></param><param name= \
save_timestamp ></param><param name= realtime ></param><param name= \
livetime >4800.00</param><param name= pixelsize >0.172 \
0.172</param><param name= beamcenter_nominal >364.80    \
209.50</param><param name= beamcenter_actual >364.82    \
209.47</param><param name= data_mean ></param><param name= data_min \
></param><param name= data_max ></param><param name= data_rms \
></param><param name= data_p10 ></param><param name= data_p90 \
></param><param name= calibrationtype >geom</param><param name= kcal \
></param><param name= pixelcal ></param><param name= koffset \
></param><param name= wavelength >1.5418</param><param name= \
detector_dist >1075.0010</param><param name= saxsconf_r1 \
>0.2000</param><param name= saxsconf_r2 >2.0000</param><param name= \
saxsconf_r3 >0.1250</param><param name= saxsconf_l1 \
>725</param><param name= saxsconf_l2 >400</param><param name= \
saxsconf_l3 >200</param><param name= detector_dist \
>1075.0010</param><param name= saxsconf_wavelength \
>1.5418</param><param name= saxsconf_dwavelength >0.004</param><param \
name= saxsconf_Imon ></param><param name= saxsconf_Ieff \
>1.12500</param><param name= saxsconf_Izero ></param><param name= \
saxsconf_det_offx >0</param><param name= saxsconf_det_offy \
>0</param><param name= saxsconf_det_rotx >0</param><param name= \
saxsconf_det_roty >0</param><param name= saxsconf_det_pixsizez \
>0.172</param><param name= saxsconf_det_pixsizey >0.172</param><param \
name= saxsconf_det_resx_0 ></param><param name= saxsconf_det_resy_0 \
></param><param name= saxsconf_abs_int_fact ></param><param name= \
sample_transfact ></param><param name= sample_thickness \
></param><param name= sample_ypos >25.000</param><param name= \
sample_zpos >33.600</param><param name= sample_angle1 \
>0.800</param><param name= sample_angle2 ></param><param name= \
sample_angle3 ></param><param name= sample_temp ></param><param name= \
sample_pressure ></param><param name= sample_strain ></param><param \
name= sample_stress ></param><param name= sample_shear_rate \
></param><param name= sample_concentration ></param><param name= \
sample_buffer ></param><param name= sample_ID ></param><param name= \
hg1 >0.399987</param><param name= hp1 >-0.001080</param><param name= \
vg1 >0.399987</param><param name= vp1 >-0.079647</param><param name= \
hg2 >4.000000</param><param name= hp2 >-0.000000</param><param name= \
vg2 >4.000000</param><param name= vp2 >0.000009</param><param name= \
hg3 >0.250000</param><param name= hp3 >-0.035193</param><param name= \
vg3 >0.250000</param><param name= vp3 >0.023757</param><param name= \
ysam >25.000000</param><param name= zsam >33.600001</param><param \
name= thsam >0.799996</param><param name= detx \
>950.001025</param><param name= dety >-1.169281</param><param name= \
detz >0.946257</param><param name= bstop >37.551200</param><param \
name= pd >30.000000</param><param name= source_type \
>GENIX3D</param><param name= source_runningtime ></param><param name= \
source_kV >49.93</param><param name= source_ma >0.60</param><param \
name= xaxis ></param><param name= xaxisfull ></param><param name= \
yaxis ></param><param name= error_norm_fact >1</param><param name= \
xaxisbintype >lin</param><param name= log >log</param><param name= \
reduction_type >s</param><param name= reduction_state ></param><param \
name= raw_filename ></param><param name= bsmask_configuration >0    \
364.80    209.50 15.0    205.00  7.5</param><param name= \
mask_filename ></param><param name= flatfield_filename \
></param><param name= empty_filename ></param><param name= \
solvent_filename ></param><param name= darkcurrent_filename \
></param><param name= readoutnoise_filename ></param><param name= \
zinger_removal >0</param><param name= data_added_constant \
>0</param><param name= data_multiplied_constant >1</param><param \
name= Img.Class ></param><param name= Img.MonitorMethod \
></param><param name= Img.ImgType >2D</param><param name= Img.Site \
>TUM</param><param name= Img.Group ></param><param name= \
Img.Researcher ></param><param name= Img.Operator ></param><param \
name= Img.Administrator ></param><param name= Meas.Description >B2: \
1554 Dec \[Lambda]=1; conf 23, Time= \
4800</param></SAXSLABparameters>", 
     "SampleFormat" -> "Two's complement signed integer data", 
     "DateTimeOriginal" -> Missing["Disputed"]|>|>}
```

Histogram:

```
imageGray = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"];

Histogram[Flatten@ImageData[imageGray], 1000000, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

```
Image@Rescale[ImageData@image, {10^-9, 10^-6}, {0.2, 1}]
```

[image]

or:

```
imageData = ImageData[imageGray];

{min, max} = MinMax[imageData];

Image[(imageData - min)/(max - min)*255]
```

[image]

Comment: it does not work on my system Mathematica v10.0.2. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: What is the result after `Options[image, MetaInformation]`? Which OS are you using?

Comment: {MetaInformation -> {}}    and windows 7 enterprise

Comment: Can you see the image after `image = Import [
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35018860/test.tiff"]`? Is `ImageDimensions[image] = {487, 619}`

Comment: I cannot see the image but yes ImageDimensions[image] = {487, 619}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50433/discussion-between-luigi-and-mrz).